# No me funciona el Jquery en este plugin

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Estoy realizando unas mejoras en un plugin, y no me funciona el Jquery. Se trata solamente de que al pulsar un botón me aparezca un modal.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnNew").click(function(){
        console.log("Botón pulsado!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        $("#newInfo").modal("show");
        alert("BOTON PULSADO");
    });
```

Y el código HTML es el siguiente:

```
<a class="page-title-action" id="btnNew" data-target="#newInfo">Agregar información adicional</a>
<br><br><br><br>

<div class="modal fade" id="newInfo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Nuevos datos</h3>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
```

Algo tan sencillo no me funciona. Tengo instalado bootstrap y css:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por qué no me funciona? ¿Se puede hacer algo al respecto?

Answer (score 2):

Estás invocando al objeto erroneo, deberias poner el id al botón para que te lo coja, tambien comprueba que tienes jquery incluido, el código para que funcione valdría con:

```js
$("#btnNew").click(function(){
  console.log("Botón pulsado!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
  //$("#newInfo").modal("show");
  alert("BOTON PULSADO");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="page-title-action" data-target="#newInfo">Agregar información adicional</a>
<br><br><br><br>

<div class="modal fade" id="newInfo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Nuevos datos</h3>
        <button id="btnNew" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```